# Appending data in see more/less operation

Tags: jquery

I've written a small script which would expand and collapse by clicking (see more/less). My issue is i have "click me" button and when i click on it div is created dynamically. But when the div is added to DOM the container does not expand automatically since height is given. **Setting the height to auto on click will solve this problem** but is there any other possible way to resolve this.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7ntQR/

code

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.truncateText = function() {
        this.each(function() {

            var el = $(this);
            var height = el.height();       //get the current height
            el.data("dht",height);          //use jquery data store to store the original height
            el.css({                        //set the height to some pixel... 
                'height':'40px'
            }); 

            var btnState = 'collapse';

            var ix = $('<div>', {
                'class':'seeMore'
            }).appendTo($(el.parent()));

            var sm = $('<span>').html('more')
            .appendTo(ix)
            .on('click' , function() {
                if(btnState == 'collapse') {                 
                        btnState = 'expand';                            
                        el.animate({
                            'height':'40px'                         
                        },500);     
                }else {                                                     
                        btnState = 'collapse';
                        el.animate({
                            'height':el.data("dht")                         
                        },500);
                }   
            });


            btnState = 'expand';

            function expand(elm) {
                elm.html('SEE LESS');                                           
            }

            function collapse(elm) {
                elm.html('more');
            }




        }); 
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Initially original height of the div is stored using data() and after that the height of div is altered to 40px.

Comment: Hey man I tried for 10 mins, I will recommend the `height: auto` **Athough** I did made a very minor change see here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeLkx/ **look for a flag called** `openState` please `:))`

Comment: hey Tats_innit when i click on "click me" the div doesn't expand i.e height remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to get the size of the div when its generated. For example get the `$('some div id').height();` And fix this height and add it to the original div which you want to expand. This would be easy to follow and to add. But I would still suggest you to go with `height:auto`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure css and keep the html in place. Here is a JS fiddle (less and more will not be displayed on IE6,7,8 and the content will be expanded)

http://jsfiddle.net/6sj4e/45/

```
.text {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%\9;
  }

input.less-more,
input.less-more:checked ~ label.more,
input.less-more:not(:checked) ~ label.less {
    display: none;
}
```

and the html :

```
<input id="chbox" class="less-more" type="checkbox">
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>
<label for="chbox" class='more'>more</label>
<label for="chbox" class='less'>less</label>
```